# query to find the value in all the tables of the database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am searching for a specific value in the table and there are lot of tables, is there a query to find the value in all the tables of the database so that I can quickly find the value without going through each table one by one.

I have already tried

```
SELECT owner, table_name, column_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE column_name LIKE '%52871%';

SELECT * from dba_objects WHERE object_name like '%52871%'
```

Answer (score 4):

You could [search for a VALUE in all COLUMNS of all TABLES in an entire SCHEMA](http://lalitkumarb.com/category/oracle-searchsortcompare-functions/) using XML SQL:

For example, I want to search for value `KING` in all columns of all the tables in entire `SCOTT` schema:

```
SQL> variable val varchar2(10)
SQL> exec :val := 'KING'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR (:val, 1, 11) "Searchword",
  2    SUBSTR (table_name, 1, 14) "Table",
  3    SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 14) "Column"
  4  FROM cols,
  5    TABLE (xmlsequence (dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype ('select '
  6    || column_name
  7    || ' from '
  8    || table_name
  9    || ' where upper('
 10    || column_name
 11    || ') like upper(''%'
 12    || :val
 13    || '%'')' ).extract ('ROWSET/ROW/*') ) ) t
 14  ORDER BY "Table"
 15  /

Searchword  Table          Column
----------- -------------- --------------
KING        EMP            ENAME
```

Comment: @PrabhdeepBhatia "Not working" is not a standard Oracle error. I have shown you a working test case from my SQL*Plus session. SQL is a language and SQL Developer is a client tool. Instead of `:val` bind variable, use `&val` as substitution variable, and enter the value when prompted. Or, simply hardcode the value in the SQL.

Comment: ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BLOB
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 288
ORA-06512: at line 1
19202. 00000 -  "Error occurred in XML processing%s"
*Cause:    An error occurred when processing the XML function